# Get current user level without using while loops?

Tags: javascript

In my messaging app, I have a level system that track's a user's activeness with XP. It doesn't store the actual level, only the amount of XP they have. Here's the function for calculating the level:

```js
function calculateLevel(num) {
  var lv = 0;
  do {
    lv++;
  } while (num >= Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv)))));
  var x = num-Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv-1))));
  var left = Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv))))-num;
  var thislv = x + left;
  return {
    level: lv,
    xp: x,
    left: left,
    next: Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv)))),
    prev: Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv-1)))),
    thislv: thislv+1
  };
}
```

The formula for calculating how much XP each level requires is 30<sup>√(√(level))</sup>. However, I don't want to use a while loop, because the app starts to slow down a bit after level 60. Is there a way to get the current level without having to use loops?

Comment: pre-calculate the XP required per level up to, 100 (or whatever you reasonably expect) then just hardcode the values and look them up. If the XP is more than what you need for level 20 but less than 21, use that.

Comment: Lookup table or cache the results of `Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(N))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the loop with

```
lv = Math.floor((Math.log(num)/Math.log(30))**4)
```

The whole function

```
function calculateLevel(num) {
  var lv = Math.floor((Math.log(num)/Math.log(30))**4);
  var x = num-Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv-1))));
  var left = Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv))))-num;
  var thislv = x + left;
  return {
    level: lv,
    xp: x,
    left: left,
    next: Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv)))),
    prev: Math.floor(Math.pow(30, Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(lv-1)))),
    thislv: thislv+1
  };
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You should rethink how you calculate level, and use for input something like: how long has user been active. Here's some example code using a library called RxJS.

```
import { fromEvent, merge } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators";

function listenForActivity() {
    let lastChecked = Date.now()
    const activities$ = merge(
        ...[
            "mousemove",
            "mousedown",
            "touchstart",
            "keydown",
            "click",
            "scroll",
        ].map((ev) => fromEvent(document, ev)),
        fromEvent(window, "focus")
    );
    return activities$.pipe(debounceTime(2000)).subscribe(() => {
        let timeActive = Date.now() - lastChecked
        calculateLevel(timeActive)
    });
}
```

Comment: read about [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while). Also, your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Unfortunate, maybe someone else can share some insight that may be more helpful.